# Why Python's multiprocessing.Queue doesn't block

Tags: python, go, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, channel

I am new to Python, but I want to write a multiproccesing program that uses `multiprocessing.Queue` as Go's channel.  However, it seems that `multiprocessing.Queue.put(, block=True)` doesn't block as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put).

Here is my Python example program:

```
import multiprocessing
import select
import time


def f(q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Put")
        q.put("hello world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=0)
    f(q)
```

I expect that it will print only one "Put" and blocks forever.  However, what I got is that it prints "Put" repeatedly.

Here is the Go program I think almost equivalent, except that goroutine is a green thread but not a process.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Put")
        ch <- 1
    }
}
```

When I type `go run csp.go`, it prints only one "Put" and the Go runtime prompts that the program is in deadlock.

Why `multiprocessing.Queue.put()` doesn't block?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=0)` - from reading the documentation this creates a queue with an infinite size: *" If maxsize is less than or equal to zero, the queue size is infinite"*. Blocking is only done when there is no place in the queue but with infinite size there is always place.

Comment: it looks like `Queue.put()` only if there are no free slots available in the queue. Did you try with `Queue(maxsize=1)`?

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich for pointing this out! I changed the program to be `q=multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)` and the program prints only two "Put"s.

Comment: @hansaplast Yes, `maxsize=1` works! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, `maxsize=0` doesn't make an unbuffered channel like in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a queue length of 1 and it will block as required

```
   Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import multiprocessing
    >>> import select
    >>> import time
    >>> 
    >>> q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)
    >>> q.put(9)
    >>> q.put(10)  // blocking here, have to ctrl-c to escape
    ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 101, in put
        if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
    KeyboardInterrupt
    >>>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I realized that the default value of `maxsize=0` indicates a buffer size of infinity instead of 0 as the Go convention after I saw @Steffen Ullrich 's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893549/why-pythons-multiprocessing-queue-doesnt-block#comment94633464_53893549